# Angular JS and btford socket.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, socket.io

I m actually facing a problem with angularjs and the Brian Ford Socket.io library.

In fact, I m trying to declare my service, and to connect my nodejs socket.io server.

The problem is, when I need to inject 'btford.socket-io', I got an error telling me that "io" is not defined...

What is wrong ?

This is my service code :

```
function SocketService(socketFactory) {

    var SocketService = socketFactory({
        ioSocket: io.connect(__ADRS_SOCKET__)
    });

    return SocketService;
}

angular
    .module('app', ['btford.socket-io'])
    .factory('SocketService', SocketService);
```

My app.js code :

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'btford.socket-io'])
    .config(config)
    .service('SocketService', SocketService);
```

And the controller where I inject the service :

```
function DashCtrl($rootScope, $scope, UserService, TraitementService, ZoneService, Notify, SocketService) {
}
```

Can you help me making it work ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: Did you include the socket.io library that's required? It's listed here: https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io#install

Comment: Ooh gosh.. I m such an idiot :/ . Thanks for all

Comment: problem persists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411413/angular-socket-io-io-is-not-defined