# angular-socket-io io is not defined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, ionic-framework, bower

There was a suggestion here: https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io/issues/127

- make sure you have socket.io client library:

  ```
  bower install socket.io-client --save
  ```

This didn't fix my problem with this same error.

- including in index.html:

  ```
  script src="lib/angular-socket-io/socket.js"
  ```
- in app.js

  ```
  angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services',       
   'starter.directives', 'btford.socket-io'])
  ```
- in services.js

  ```
  .factory('seatStatusSocket',function(socketFactory){ 
     var myIoSocket = io.connect(porturl); // io is not defined here, suddenly.
  ```
- It was working before, using a remote copy of the lib. When this error started, I changed index.html to link a local copy, as this remote version also received a Bad Gateway error (now fine, but still socket io is not defined as above).

removed:

```
script src="http://chat.socket.io/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

versions

```
socket.io@1.3.7 node_modules/socket.io
node --version
v0.12.7
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to include in index.html:

```
script src="<bowerComponentPath>/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"
```

before this:

```
script src="<bowerComponentPath>/angular-socket-io/socket.js"
```

and yest this is required:

```
bower install socket.io-client --save
```

Comment: Thanks! that was it! I thought I had 2 of the same, so I removed the first socket.io-client when it had a Bad Gateway error. When I changed to a different working url version of that, it worked.

Comment: Dear reader: This was my solution. Hope it helps. https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/766